# How to assign a static VPN private ip to client over Azure Basic P2S VPN

Tags: azure, vpn

Can anyone suggest how to assign a static IP from VPN private IP range to the client for Azure basic P2S VPN connection. Also if anyone can guide me if I can connect the Azure VM to on-premise client VM over the on-premise network private IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning static IP addresses to VPN clients with P2S VPN isn't currently supported.

When client connects to P2S the next available IP is allocated.

You can raise your feedback via User Voice:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/33929980-static-ip-for-vpn-client-over-azure-p2s-solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/234465/azure-p2s-vpn-assign-static-ip.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also previously found this blog, but in search of last hope I just posted my query. Need to move to site to site one